# A sequence ${\bf x}_1,{\bf x}_2,{\bf x}_3,...$ converges geometrically in some norm, will it converge geometrically in any equivalent norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

If a sequence ${\bf x}_1,{\bf x}_2,{\bf x}_3,...$ converges geometrically to a vector ${\bf u}$ in norm $\|\cdot\|_1$, i.e. $\|{\bf x}_i - {\bf u}\|_1 \le q\|{\bf x}_{i-1} - {\bf u}\|_1$ for some $q\in (0,1)$, will it converge geometrically in any norm $\|\cdot\|_2$ that is equivalent to $\|\cdot\|_1$?

Suppose $c_1\|\cdot\|_2 \le \|\cdot\|_1 \le c_2\|\cdot\|_2$ for some $0<c_1 \le c_2$. I think ${\bf x}_1,{\bf x}_2,{\bf x}_3,...$ converges to $\bf u$ in $\|\cdot\|_2$, through a simple $\epsilon$-arugment. However, I **cannot** see the convergence is also geometric in $\|\cdot\|_2$. If it is indeed not, can anyone help give a counterexample? Thanks!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I fixed that error in post. Thanks!

Comment: Is the notion of converging geometrically useful? I was surprised this wasn't a question about converging exponentially i.e. $\|\mathbf x_n-\mathbf u\|_1\leq Cq^n$ for some $C>0$ and some $0<q<1.$

Comment: That rigid definition of "converge geometrically" is not practical in, say, numerical analysis, where very very few methods have such strong monotonic convergence structure. A definition with more "slack" is that $\| \mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{u} \| \leq C q^i$ where $q \in (0,1)$, and in this case you actually can prove the result you want here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $\mathbf x_n=(\tfrac 1 {2^n},0)$ for odd $n$ and $\mathbf x_n=(\tfrac 1 {2^n},\tfrac 1 {2^n})$ for even $n$. Then $\mathbf x_n$ converges geometrically to zero in $\mathbb R^2$ with the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm. But it does not converge geometrically with the $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm because $\mathbf x_{2n-1}$ and $\mathbf x_{2n}$ have the same $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm, $\tfrac{1}{2^{2n-1}}$.

Comment: Nice simple example.....BTW.  Suppose we say that $(x_n)_n$ converges quasi-geometrically to $0$ iff there exists $A>0$ and $B\in [0,1)$ such that $\|x_n\|\leq AB^n$ for all sufficiently large $n.$ Since any two equivalent norms on a normed vector space are  uniformly equivalent,  if  $(x_n)_n$ converges quasi-geometrically to $0$ with respect to a norm then it will do so with respect to any ewuivalent norm.